# AngularJS how to get notified when cookie is expired

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cookies

I have an AngularJS-App (1.4.0) running.

After the user logs in, the token from the server gets stored in this singleton service.

```
angular.module('logit').factory('SessionManager' , SessionManager);

function SessionManager($http,$cookies,$rootScope) {

    var SessionManager = {};
    var user = null;
    var token = null;

    SessionManager.login = function(username,password,success,error) {
    $http.post(
        $rootScope.url + "rest-auth/login/",
        {'username':username,'password':password}).success(
        function(data){
            SessionManager.setToken(data.key);
            SessionManager.loadUser(success,error);
        }).error(
        function(err){
            if(error != null)error(err);
        });
};

SessionManager.logout = function(success,error){
    $http.post($rootScope.url+"rest-auth/logout/").success(
        function(data){
            SessionManager.setToken(null);
            user = null;
            if(success != null)success(data);
        }).error(function(err){
            SessionManager.setToken(null)
            if(error != null)error(err);
        });
};

SessionManager.setToken = function( newToken ) {
    token = newToken;

    if(newToken != null){
        if($cookies.get("token") == null){
            //Token als Cookie für 30 Tage speichern speichern
            var expireDate = new Date();
            expireDate.setSeconds(expireDate.getSeconds() + 5);
            $cookies.put("token",newToken,{'expires': expireDate});
        }
    }else{
        $cookies.remove("token");
    }

    $http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]=(newToken != null)?"Token " + newToken:null;
};

SessionManager.loadUser = function(success, error){
    $http.get("http://localhost:7777/rest-auth/user/").success(
        function(data){
            user = data;
            if(success != null)success(data);
        }
    ).error(function(err){
            if(error != null)error(err);
        }
    );
};

SessionManager.getToken = function() {
    return token;
};

SessionManager.isLoggedIn = function(){
    return SessionManager.getToken() != null;
}

SessionManager.getUser = function(){
    return user;
}

return SessionManager;
```

In addition it gets stored in a cookie. I check in the run function if the token exists, if so i store it in the service.

```
    if($cookies.get("token") != null){
        SessionManager.setToken($cookies.get("token"));
    }
```

I now wanna show the login-screen if the cookie is expired (with an interceptor).

The cookie gets deleted correctly from the browser when it expires. But my token is still stored in the service. How can i know that the cookie is not present? Should i check for the cookie on each $http request? 
This looks like a overkill for me.

Whats the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: get the difference from `now` until the time that the token will be expired. create a $timeout that will fire a function which change the user status to `unathorized`. Of course you will have to store the cookie expiration day as part of the cookie string, not so safe.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't thought about that :). Why would it be not so safe? And how can i prevent it? There must be a save best practise for this usecase.

Comment: Because the user will is able to change that string. Although he is not able to change the real expiration date.